# Acumatica Contract Based API SalesOrder.Detail is returning null when working through I210 course material

Tags: c#, acumatica

I am actively working through the I210 course material on the Contract-Based API. I am doing the exercises on the most recent version 2018 R2 so I assume there may be some differences that may be causing this issue.

The first example that returns an issue is in *Example 4.1.2*
When the code reaches this line
`SalesOrderDetail orderLine = order.Details.Single(...`
The details property is null which in turn raises an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." exception.
Many other examples after this also call for SalesOrder.Details which also returns the same exception.

Any help pointing me in the right direction on getting this to work on the 2018 R2 version will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
Robert

```
// Updating the detail lines of a sales order
public static void UpdateSO(DefaultSoapClient soapClient)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Updating a sales order...");

    //Sales order data
    string orderType = "SO";
    string customerOrder = "SO248-563-06"; 

    // A unique value that
    // identifies a sales order
    string firstItemInventoryID = "CONTABLE1";
    string firstItemWarehouse = "MAIN";
    string secondItemInventoryID = "AALEGO500";
    string secondItemWarehouse = "MAIN";
    decimal secondItemQuantity = 4;

    // Find the sales order to be updated
    SalesOrder soToBeFound = new SalesOrder
    {
        OrderType = new StringSearch { Value = orderType },
        CustomerOrder = new StringSearch { Value = customerOrder },
    };

    SalesOrder order = (SalesOrder)soapClient.Get(soToBeFound);

    // Find the line to be deleted and mark it for deletion
    // The Single method makes the program find
    // the only SalesOrderDetail of order.Details
    // that has the specified InventoryID and WarehouseID
    SalesOrderDetail orderLine = order.Details.Single(orderLineToBeDeleted =>
                                                      orderLineToBeDeleted.InventoryID.Value == firstItemInventoryID &&
                                                      orderLineToBeDeleted.WarehouseID.Value == firstItemWarehouse);
    orderLine.Delete = true;

    // Find the line to be updated and update the quantity in it
    orderLine = order.Details.Single(orderLineToBeUpdated => orderLineToBeUpdated.InventoryID.Value == secondItemInventoryID &&
                                     orderLineToBeUpdated.WarehouseID.Value == secondItemWarehouse);

    orderLine.Quantity = new DecimalValue { Value = secondItemQuantity };

    // Clear the Hold check box
    order.Hold = new BooleanValue { Value = false };

    // Update the sales order
    order = (SalesOrder)soapClient.Put(order);

    // Display the summary of the updated record
    Console.WriteLine("Order type: " + order.OrderType.Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Order number: " + order.OrderNbr.Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Ordered quantity: " + order.OrderedQty.Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Order total: " + order.OrderTotal.Value);
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest reviewing the formatting a bit, as it is now it's a pretty cumbersome read, specially the code

Comment: I edited the question to format code sample. Pretty sure it was intentionally un-indented because SO RTF editor often breaks on indented code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Details are not returned, this is an optimization to retrieve the master document faster. The trick is to use the [ReturnBehavior](https://help.acumatica.com/Wiki/ShowExport.aspx?PageID=7b6ecfb4-faf6-4125-a4ae-a23a57662f3f&type=txt) property. You will also need to declare the Details collection in the web service call.

Code:

```
SalesOrder soToBeFound = new SalesOrder
{
    ReturnBehavior = ReturnBehavior.All,
    OrderType = new StringSearch { Value = orderType },
    CustomerOrder = new StringSearch { Value = customerOrder },
    Details = new SalesOrderDetail[]
    {
        new SalesOrderDetail { ReturnBehavior = ReturnBehavior.All }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Everything worked as expected once I added the return behavior. Sorry about the code formatting. this was my first stack overflow question and I am unfamiliar with how to format.

Comment: Don't mind about it, I had same difficulty with SO formatting. You can mark my answer as accepted (checkmark) if the solution works.

Comment: It says I need to collect 15 experience points before I can mark as answered. I think that is silly being I asked the question. I should be able to have a say if its answered or not. There was some other stuff I found but solved that might help others if I post about it. Maybe that would up my experience points.

Comment: No problem, this site is useful but has lots of silly rules.

Comment: @RobertWaite IIRC you need 15 reputation points to upvote, but none to accept an answer.